# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() not working in Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-sdcard

As i need to load a file from SDCard when i am using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` or `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` but it is not working, well it works great with the `"file:///sdcard/Avalon/assets/www/filename.html"`. I don't know what is happening with my path

```
cwv.loadUrl(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Avalon/assets/www/filename.html", map);
```

I want make my path generic that's why i need to work it with any generic term...

Comment: Android does not provide a function which reliably returns the path to an removeble sd card. You have to make a provision so the user can indicate the right directory. In your settings for example.

Comment: What is not in your post is what ....getAbsolutePath() returns. Even if getExter.... Would give the right path it would not work as you forgot the file:// in front.

Comment: Great it works... Actually i forgot to add file://
This is my mistake thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great it works... Actually i forgot to add "file://"
So actual path should be

```
cwv.loadUrl("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Avalon/assets/www/filename.html", map);
```

This is my mistake thanks